# Find all links within a div using lxml

Tags: python, web-crawler, lxml, python-2.x, mechanize-python

I'm writing a tool that needs a collect all urls within a div on a web page but no urls outside that div. Simplified the page it looks something like this:

```
<div id="bar">
   <a link I dont want>
   <div id="foo">
      <lots of html>
      <h1 class="baz">
         <a href=”link I want”>
      </h1>
      <h1 class="caz">
         <a href=“link I want”>
      </h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

When selecting the div with Firebug and selecting XPath i get: //*[@id="foo"]. So far so good. However I'm stuck at trying to find all urls inside the div foo. Please help me find a way to extract the url defined by the href in a elements.

Example code similar to what I'm working on using w3schools:

```
import mechanize
import lxml.html
import cookielib

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'WatcherBot')]

r = br.open('http://w3schools.com/')
html = br.response().read()
root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

hrefs = root.xpath('//*[@id="leftcolumn"]')

# Found no solution yet. Stuck
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
hrefs = root.xpath('//div[@id="foo"]//a/@href')
```

This will give you a list of all `href` values from `a` tags inside `<div id="foo">` at any level